# Json Creation Response not getting as required

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to create JSON using below code

```
test(array) {
  var map = {};
  var tt = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      var obj = array[i];
      var items = obj.items;

       var child = Array.prototype.map.call(items, s => s.displayName);

      map[obj.displayName] = {
        child
      };
  }

  return map;

}
```

Expected Response:

```
{
  RoleManagement: [
    'Create',
    'Edit',
    'Delete',
    'Change permissions'],
  UserManagement: [
    'Create',
    'Edit',
    'Delete',
    'Change permissions'
  ]
}
```

Error Response

Input Image
[Input Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhSll.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYIoR.png
I Dont need child just array of create,update,delete

Please help me out

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please put the input for which you want the expected result.

Comment: Hi Sajeeb, Check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYIoR.png, I am getting child of array bit I don't need child key only array of values

Comment: Can you provide the original input? `test(array)` - how your array looks like?

Comment: Hi @MaraBlack https://i.ibb.co/X2BTcHK/image.png Check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the place, you have done a mistake.

```
map["RoleManagement"] = {
        child
      };
```

For Example,Assume creating a new property "RoleManagement" inside the map object.

> Based on you expected response, you wants to create a "RoleManagement" property, that contains array['Create','Edit','Delete','Change permissions'].

Instead, you are trying to create "RoleManagement" property as an object inside the map object.

**Try this**

```
//child contains the array

map["RoleManagement"] = child;
```

Here,You are initializing the property with array.

It Will solve your issue.